# How can i get DATA from TIME?

Tags: php, mysql

i have the table NAMES

and i've the following register on this table

```
NAME='Jose'
PASSWD='Maria'
POINTS='2000'
TIMESTAMP='2011-03-17 21:16:17' //field tipe TIMESTAMP
```

and another register

```
NAME='Pedro'
PASSWD='Paulo'
POINTS='4000'
TIMESTAMP='2011-02-16 00:00:00'
```

if i made the query like this

```
SELECT NOME FROM NAMES WHERE TIMESTAMP < '2011-03-17'
```

this query will return only the NAME "Pedro", because his TIMESTAMP are smaller than data that i put in the query (2011-03-17)

but what i want is..

Let's imagine what in the day 15/03 Jose has 2000 points, and in the day 16/03 he has 5000 points. How do i know how many points he has in the day 15/03 on today (18/03)?. This MySQL field tipe "TIMESTAMP" will return to me only registers that was updated before the query data, but this is not what i want.

What i want is take the value X that their field has in the day Y.

Answer (score 0):

```
select nome from names where date(timestamp) = '2011-03-15';
```

Comment: i'll try be more especific..

i want make a graphic of users account evolution, taking POINTS value of four days ago until today, putting they on the graphic.

if i use the query select * from NAMES where TIMESTAMP = '2011-03-15'; this will return 0 registers, because the value of the field TIMESTAMP isn't 2011-03-15, in the really is 2011-03-18, you understand?

Comment: So you want to have the query return a range of days, whether or not a user has any points registered for that day?

Comment: exactly, i want to get these days with their values from an register.

Comment: Can't do that without some SQL extensions that aren't on all servers. But you can generate a temporary table with the dates listed, and join your names table against that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737378/generate-sql-temp-table-of-sequential-dates-to-left-outer-join-to